# powershell move file type .file

Tags: powershell

I have files that do not have file extensions.  How can I move them in powershell?

Here's what i have:

```
$backupPATH = new-item -ItemType directory C:\Users\user\Desktop\location\$(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss)
$date = (get-date).AddDays(-60)
get-childitem -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\test1 *.tsv |
where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date} |
move-item -destination $backupPATH
```

Below is script to move files without extension but not sure where to start.

```
get-childitem -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\test1 |
where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date} |
move-item -destination $backupPATH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter on files whose `Extension` property is empty:

```
get-childitem -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\test1 |
where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date -and -not  $_.Extension} |
move-item -destination $backupPATH
```

Comment: Here is the **power** of the shell :)

Comment: Yes! Worked like a charm.  Thanks very much! :)